# HTTP requests to JSON in Google Drive

Tags: json, google-drive-api, drive, json-server

Do you guys know a way I can make HTTP requests to a JSON storaged in Google Drive?
I can do Get with the right link, but, what about POST, PUT and DELETE?
Thank you all

Drive's link let me do GET but can't Post

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `make HTTP requests to a JSON storaged in Google Drive`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Don't worry, I think I can't do that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that I cannot understand your question.